# Spark Flume streaming - missing packages?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I try to execute the example of flume streaming but can't have my jars files working : 
Here 
https://github.com/spark-packages/dstream-flume/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/flume_wordcount.py
they point out on

```
bin/spark-submit --jars \
      external/flume-assembly/target/scala-*/spark-streaming-flume-assembly-*.jar
```

I have no clue what is this "external" dir ?

On my spark (1.6.0)  lib I put several jars (I tried both 1.6.0 and 1.6.0) :

```
$ pwd
/Users/romain/Informatique/zoo/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib
$ ls *flume*
spark-streaming-flume-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar   
spark-streaming-flume-assembly_2.10-1.6.2.jar   

spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10-1.6.2.jar
spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10-1.6.0.jar

spark-streaming-flume_2.10-1.6.0.jar
spark-streaming-flume_2.10-1.6.2.jar
```

Then I do a :

```
    $ ./bin/pyspark --master ip:7077 --total-executor-cores 1 --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0 
--jars /Users/romain/Informatique/zoo/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10-1.6.0.jar 
--jars /Users/romain/Informatique/zoo/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-streaming-flume_2.10-1.6.0.jar 
--jars /Users/romain/Informatique/zoo/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-streaming-flume-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar
```

The python notebook server fires up, but then When I ask for a storm object:

```
from pyspark.streaming.flume import FlumeUtils
from pyspark           import SparkContext
from pyspark           import SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
try    : sc.stop()
except : pass
try    : ssc.stop()
except : pass
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("Streaming Flume")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory","1g")
conf.set("spark.driver.memory","1g")
conf.set("spark.cores.max","5")
conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/Users/romain/Informatique/zoo/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/")
conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/Users/romain/Informatique/zoo/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/")
sc  = SparkContext(conf=conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
FlumeUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost", "4949")
```

it fails :

```
________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Spark Streaming's Flume libraries not found in class path. Try one of the following.

  1. Include the Flume library and its dependencies with in the
     spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-flume:1.6.0 ...

  2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/,
     Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-flume-assembly, Version = 1.6.0.
     Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-flume-assembly.jar> ...

________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I have tried to add

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-flume-sink.1.6.0
```

at the end of my spark-submit, but I get another issue :

```
org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-flume-sink added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
:: resolution report :: resolve 2344ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
    :: modules in use:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-flume-sink;1.6.0

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/Users/romain/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-flume-sink/1.6.0/spark-streaming-flume-sink-1.6.0.pom

      -- artifact org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-flume-sink;1.6.0!spark-streaming-flume-sink.jar:

      file:/Users/romain/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-flume-sink/1.6.0/spark-streaming-flume-sink-1.6.0.jar

    ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

      /Users/romain/.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-flume-sink/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-flume-sink/1.6.0/spark-streaming-flume-sink-1.6.0.pom

      -- artifact org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-flume-sink;1.6.0!spark-streaming-flume-sink.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-flume-sink/1.6.0/spark-streaming-flume-sink-1.6.0.jar

    ==== spark-packages: tried

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-flume-sink/1.6.0/spark-streaming-flume-sink-1.6.0.pom

      -- artifact org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-flume-sink;1.6.0!spark-streaming-flume-sink.jar:

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-flume-sink/1.6.0/spark-streaming-flume-sink-1.6.0.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-flume-sink;1.6.0: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-flume-sink;1.6.0: not found]
```

I never used a pom.xml - maybe I should ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake : the jars file I downloaded were empty !

:-(((((
the mistake came from  =
curl -O http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10/1.6.2/spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10-1.6.2.jar
downloading only an html file :-(